# Smooth Graph of csv data

Tags: python, pandas

I got data, thats data frame looks like this:

[image]

I plotted the data to get this plot:

[image]

Now I would like to smooth the graph. I tried the following:

```
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
x = df["Zeit"]
y = df["Kanal A"]

w = savgol_filter(y, 501, 2)
plt.plot(x, w, 'b')
```

The Plot I got is shown here:

[image]

Does any of you got a proper solution to smoothe or filter this graphs in a proper way? I would like to get a smooth filtered curve over the given plot.

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: `sns.regplot(x, w, lowess=True)`

Comment: There are many, many ways to filter data in `scipy`.  Perhaps a Butterworth low-pass filter would do what you want.

Comment: "a proper solution" - what's wrong with the solution in your post? You could also try [the Hodrick-Prescott filter](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.filters.hp_filter.hpfilter.html), for example. Or a simple moving average, a.k.a. `df["Kanal A"].rolling(30).mean()`.

Comment: You might want to use log scale for x-axis. The variable `Zeit` is not uniformly distributed from 0 to 1.6 and thus, I think the plot is not smooth. Can you try `plt.xscale('log')` after `plt.plot(...)` and check if it works for you?